# .exe Packaging for Python files with ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, python-2.7, arcgis-10.4

I've written a little program that's meant to function as a stand-alone, not as an add-in. I'd like to be able to pack it up as an .exe, rather than ask my users to run the script. It does import ArcPy.

I tried pyinstaller, py2exe, cx_Freeze, several other things ... 
I cannot wrap this thing up into an executable. Can't figure it out.

I found cx_Freeze the least ornery thus far, yet I still cannot pack up my Python (2.7) into an executable successfully. 
What am I missing?

Here is the error I continue to receive:

**import arcgis scripting
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.**

(The image is an example of what the error looks like. I'm using ArcGis 10.4)

[image]

I see in the ESRI community that someone else had this problem as well, 5 years ago, scroll to bottom of link: 
https://community.esri.com/thread/57485

Yet, no answer from the ESRI community.

Here is my code, feel free to chuckle. All the additional mods and included files are from chasing around error messages until I was stumped.

This file, setup.py, is in the same PyCharm Project with my program:

```
import sys
import os.path
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import arcpy

# source:
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoHWJV8iVTQ

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.5')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.5')


additional_mods = ["numpy.core._methods", "numpy.lib.format"]
# Dependencies
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "include_files": ["sqlite3.dll", "tcl85.dll", "tclpip85.dll", "tk85.dll"],
                     "includes": additional_mods}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(script="MyProgramINeed.py", base=base, icon="myiconineed.ico")
setup(   name = "MyProgramINeed",
         version = "0.1",
         description = "description of my program",
         options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
         executables = [exe])
```

Comment: 10.3 is an elderly release of ArcGIS (to be retired in Dec).  You're much more likely to find success with the Anaconda-ready Python 3.8 ArcPy that ships with ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Maybe you missed this link in your search https://community.esri.com/thread/164101.

Comment: ArcGIS version is a really unlikely a factor here. I've tried a task like this in the past, using py2exe and __think__ I was successful (it was so long ago). Per this https://community.esri.com/thread/164101 - try py2exe, and make sure you do an exclude on arcpy, you don't want to bundle it, you want to make sure you have a proper __reference__ to it setup.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link per the suggestions of KHibma and GBG. Using py2exe, excluding arcpy, chasing around the DLLs to exclude, and then adding the site-packages folder with .PTH in the executable's build folder ...still just getting a flash of a black window pop-up that immediately disappears when trying to run the built executable. Chasing this error: 
"The following modules appear to be missing
['_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'sitecustomize', 'usercustomize']
"

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364264/py2exe-executable-packaging-with-arcpy-the-following-modules-appear-to-be-miss